# calculation of differences of dates in Swift 3

Tags: swift3

I have created 3 outlets for labels,1 action for button and 1 outlet for UIDatePickerView. lblField displays the current date with month, date and year[January 25, 2017] format. lblField2 displays the selected dates by the user after pressing dueDate action. Now, I need to calculate the differences between the current date and selected date i.e (lblField2 - lblField) in lblField3. How can i show the difference value in months and days in Swift3. I need strictly for Swift3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dateComponentsFormatter` for that.

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.month,.day]
formatter.maximumUnitCount = 2
formatter.unitsStyle = .full
lblField3.text = formatter.string(from: Date(), to: datePicker.date) ?? ""
```

If you want difference with month and day specific that you can use `Calendar` this way.

```
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day], from: Date(), to: datePicker.date)
let dayDifference = components.day!
let monthDifference = components.month!
```

Comment: It gives only months but not days. I need both months and days @Nirav D

Comment: @Tamannah Check the edited answer once and set `maximumUnitCount` to `2`

Comment: @NiravD Not any optional must be *nil coalescing* checked. In case of date components you 100% safely specified the `month` and `day` component so the corresponding properties cannot – never – be `nil`. Apple changed the properties to optionals to be able to use the convenient initializer `DateComponents(hour:12, minute:30)` omitting all unused components.

Comment: Where shall I add that ?? And how to display both on lblField3( as 6 moths 18 days).  I have given all codes.. Please help me out!!  @ Nirav D

Comment: @Tamannah Check my latest edited answer and add `DateComponentsFormatter` in your `dueDate` action method.

Comment: It came in format as 2 months, 22 days. Cant i display as 2 months & 22 days ? @Nirav D

Comment: @Tamannah For that you can simply replace `,` to `&` using `replacingOccurrences(of:with:)` method.

Comment: Where should i do it ?? sort me this out and all will be fine. @ Nirav D

Comment: @Tamannah You need to simply write it like this way `lblField3.text = formatter.string(from: fromDate, to: toDate)?.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: " &") ?? ""`

Comment: Ohh thanx sir @ Nirav D

Answer (score 0):

```
        var date = NSDate().dateStringWithFormat(format: "dd.MM.YYY")
    print(date)
```

**15.02.2017** 
this will be the date formater easy and new single line sytax